# Cannot open New python3 in jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am trying in all ways to open a new Python 3 ipynb file from jupyter. I tried brew uninstalling jupyter, updating python3 and following the steps described here: https://medium.com/@iamclement/how-to-install-jupyter-notebook-on-mac-using-homebrew-528c39fd530f.

The result however is always the same, i.e. the one describe in the picture: every time I try to open a new ipynb from jupyter, the options are Python 2 and two types that I mistakenly (and honestly I do not know how I made it) created from conda env. Is there a way to uninstall jupyter and just have the two options Python 2 and Python 3 when clicking on New?

[image]

Comment: You seem to be mixing and matching. If you choose to opt in to add & use conda, as you say "created from conda env", then that is your main package manager and is what you should use to install things to make robust, portable environments. You shouldn't then follow the steps you link to [there](https://medium.com/@iamclement/how-to-install-jupyter-notebook-on-mac-using-homebrew-528c39fd530f). And what you are seeing is a feature, not a bug. You want to use conda so that you can keep your different projects running as the specific versions of Python 3 and packages change.

Comment: @Wayne thank you for the adding. I just wonder how I can remove the conda envs from the window that I open up in jupyter.

Comment: On a clean, new computer, don't use Anaconda and install Jupyter without it. Then install ipykernel, too. You experience isn't going to be as nice though for project management. You never said if those other choices give you Python 3, by the way? I suspect they do as by default these data most things are Python 3.